# Cypress on Github Actions constantly fails to fetch in a before handler

Tags: cypress, github-actions, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I want to reset my database/server between every test scenario.
For this I somehow need to communicate from Cypress to my backend server.

I thought I could do this:

```
  Cypress.on('test:before:run:async', async function () {
    const url = location.protocol + '//127.0.0.1:' + (Number(location.port) + 1) + '/';
    await fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' });
  });
```

With a very simple http server spawned by the backend that will reset the backend when it receives a call.

This test before handler happens to be run right before every scenario defined by cucumber, so it's a perfect fit.

This works perfectly fine on my local machine. However it fails on Github actions.

I've tried:

- run electron or chrome
- run headfull
- set chrome web security to false
- use XMLHttpRequest instead
- set CORS headers on the server in the backend

All these options and various combinations of them work just fine on my local machine, but the error on github actions stays the same.

The error message is rather short: "Failed to fetch"
or with XMLHttpRequest instead it produces status 0 and an empty status text.

What can I do to debug this? I would basically need access to the browser on github actions.

EDIT:
When I test fetch on the same origin it works, but I cannot reset the database that way.
So this does appear to be a CORS issue, just that I've tried to set no-cors, add cors heads and set chrome web security to false all at the same time already.

Comment: I've "solved" this by providing a proxy in my normal backend server to the server on the port + 1, but that's a horrible hack. Still looking for anybody who can tell me why this would happen or how to better implement this kind of thing.